# Zipkin trace id lost on producerTemplate

Tags: apache-camel, zipkin, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

I have an api which is called through rest and then sends message to camel queue, on which new trace id is created instead of using the initial one, tried manually setting "X-B3-TraceId" header, but looks like it getting overridden still. Am I missing something for it to be passed over? my ZipkinTracer config looks like this:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ZipkinTracer.class)
ZipkinTracer zipkin(final CamelContext camelContext) {

    ZipkinTracer zipkin = new ZipkinTracer();
    zipkin.setPort(9411);
    zipkin.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    zipkin.setRate(1f);
    zipkin.setEndpoint("http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans");
    OkHttpSender sender = OkHttpSender.create("http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans");
    zipkin.setSpanReporter(AsyncReporter.create(sender));
    camelContext.setTracing(true);
    zipkin.init(camelContext);

    return zipkin;
}
```

And I send a message by constructing an exchange object and passing it to producerTemplate.

```
producerTemplate.send(startEndpoint, exchange)
```

Comment: How are you propagating trace context?

Comment: tried setting message headers/exchange properties from Tracer object before sending the message, but that does nothing.

Comment: >but that does nothing

Are you sure? Doesn't it add the new header with name? B3 has multiple formats, are you using multi header format?

Comment: I was setting it from the constants class from that lib, so I would assume, that the format should be correct. One thing worth mentioning is that in that API we are using quite old version of spring boot(1.5.9.RELEASE)/spring cloud(1.4.0.RELEASE), I wonder if that could cause any issues.

Comment: did you find a solution?